# How to Remove Element from Lists with Specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two lists and I'd like to remove all `li` tags except for those li tags that contain input elements with `-all` as its `id`. Is this something I can achieve using selectors in jQuery? Possibly using not selector?

This is what I currently have: `$("#search-filter-column ul li").remove();`

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-types-suv" name="filter-types-suv" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-types-special" name="filter-types-special" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>


<ul>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-company-all" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-company-1" name="filter-company-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-company-2" name="filter-company-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>


<ul>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-location-1" name="filter-location-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-location-2" name="filter-location-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input id="filter-location-3" name="filter-location-3" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of searching for `<li>` elements and then testing their content, you can test for `input` elements that are inside of `li` elements and then use the **[`:not()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** and the **["ends-with" attribute selector (`$=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** along with the **["starts-with" (`^=`) attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** to exclude any irrelevant `input` elements. Then, you can remove the parent `li` of any matching elements with the **[Jquery `.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method.

```js
// Remove all input elements that are descendants of an <li> that don't have
// an id that ends with ($=) "all" or an id that starts with "filter-location-".
$("#search-filter-column ul > li input:not([id$='-all']):not([id^='filter-location-'])").parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-filter-column">
<ul>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-types-suv" name="filter-types-suv" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-types-special" name="filter-types-special" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-company-all" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-company-1" name="filter-company-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-company-2" name="filter-company-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-location-1" name="filter-location-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-location-2" name="filter-location-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="filter-location-3" name="filter-location-3" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! What does $= mean?

Comment: @Michael See my updated answer. It means "ends-with" because you want the input elements who's `id` "end-with `-all`.

Comment: Quick question: Just ran into an issue lol, what if I wanted to remove all li elements that don't have filter-location- AND -all as the ID? Can we add an OR to the selector?

Comment: @Michael Can you clarify. The `id` should be what? I don't see any elements in your example with an `id` that contains `filter-location`.

Comment: I also have li elements that contain `-location-`. I don't want to remove these li elements either. Right now when using the above, it's removing these elements.

Comment: @Michael: You can have multiple `:not` conditions, `li:not(this):not(that)`. They AND together like other aspects of CSS selectors.

Comment: I updated the post with new list containing -location-

Comment: @Michael I had to step out, but I've updated the answer to address this. You just string multiple `:not()` CSS pseudo-class selectors together to create more conditions. In your newest case, you'd use the "contains" (`*=`) attribute selector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), and an [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$("#search-filter-column ul li:not(:has(input[id$=-all]))").remove();
```

That matches `li` elements in a `ul` in `#search-filter_column` that don't contain an `input` whose `id` ends with `-all`.

In a comment elsewhere you've said

> I also have li elements that contain -location-. I don't want to remove these li elements either.

You can have multiple `:not` conditions, `li:not(this):not(that)`. They AND together like other aspects of CSS selectors. So you'd do that like this with an [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`*=`):

```
$("#search-filter-column ul li:not(:has(input[id$=-all])):not(:has(input[id*=-location-]))").remove();
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#search-filter-column ul li:not(:has(input[id$=-all])):not(:has(input[id*=-location-]))").remove();
```

```html
<div id="search-filter-column">
  Types:
  <ul>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-suv" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-special" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
  </ul>

  Companies:
  <ul>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-all" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-1" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-2" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
  </ul>
  
  Locations:
  <ul>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-location-1" name="filter-location-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-location-2" name="filter-location-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-location-3" name="filter-location-3" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! What does $= mean?

Comment: @Michael: That's the attribute-ends-with selector. More in the link above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `filter` function for this in order to filter out the elements you do not want to remove:

```js
$("#search-filter-column ul li").filter(function() { 
  return $(this).find('input[id$=-all]').length;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-filter-column">
  <ul>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-suv" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-types-special" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
  </ul>


  <ul>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-all" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-1" name="filter-company-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
     <li>
         <input id="filter-company-2" name="filter" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In your example, I changed a few filters to not have -all in the id, to show that it will, in fact, remove those.

Answer (score -4):

You try to select by ID, get parent and remove parent.
Ex:

```
$('#ID_REMOVE').parent().remove()
```